# Unity Issue With Creating Sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm not entirely sure what to do here, I have the line of code

```c#
Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(spriteTexture, 
    new Rect(0, 0, spriteTexture.width, spriteTexture.height), 
    new Vector2(0, 0), 
    pixelsPerUnit, 
    0, 
    spriteType);
```

And for that line of code I get the error message

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I really do not know what I am doing wrong here

```c#
Sprite NewSprite = new Sprite();
```

Doesn't work cause of its constructor, I'm sure I'm being silly but I would really appreciate some input :)

EDIT: Apologies for omitting my code:

```c#
public static class ImageToSprite
{

public static Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D tex2D;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        tex2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);

        if(tex2D.LoadImage(fileData))
        {
            return tex2D;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static Sprite LoadNewSprite(string filePath, float pixelsPerUnit = 100.0f, SpriteMeshType spriteType = SpriteMeshType.Tight)
{
    Texture2D spriteTexture = LoadTexture(filePath);
    Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(spriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, spriteTexture.width, spriteTexture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), pixelsPerUnit, 0, spriteType);

    return newSprite;
}

public static Sprite ConvertTextureToSprite(Texture2D texture, float PixelsPerUnit = 100.0f, SpriteMeshType spriteType = SpriteMeshType.Tight)
{
    // Converts a Texture2D to a sprite, assign this texture to a new sprite and return its reference

    Sprite NewSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), PixelsPerUnit, 0, spriteType);

    return NewSprite;
}
}
```

And here is the link to where I got this code from : https://forum.unity.com/threads/generating-sprites-dynamically-from-png-or-jpeg-files-in-c.343735/

Comment: are you sure `spriteTexture` is set? Can you show us the rest of your code please?

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! But I'ld suggest to close your question. It is very unlikely that it helps any other user since the issue was caused by an error in a custom method.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I apologize for my silliness but the problem was solved very easily, I was returning null (from the loadtexture function) and had no fail safe at all, I apologize for the waste of time.